# ASP.NET MVC. Доступ к данным из готовой базы данных mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc, mysqlconnector

Доброго времени суток!

Изучая реализацию MVC-паттерна средствами ASP.NET и читая множество туториалов по созданию веб-приложений с помощью этих средств, я заметил, что почти везде навязывают использование именно MS SQL Server, т.к. он отлично интегрируется с Visual Studio.

Но так как до этого базы данных я создавал в MySQL Workbench, то она мне ближе по степени удобства работы. Пытался найти на просторах интернета способы получения данных из mysql database, но ничего конкретного и полезного не нашел.
Находил вот что:

- [metanit](https://metanit.com/sharp/articles/mvc/23.php) предлагает автоматическую генерацию базы данных на основе модели, что меня не очень устраивает.
- [статья на сайте microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/implementing-a-custom-mysql-aspnet-identity-storage-provider) предлагает создать базу данных в Azure, потом с помощью mysql worckbench соединиться с Azure, но в самом приложении данные только добавляются, они не считываются с базы данных.
- На официальном [сайте MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-project-items-mvc.html) использовали технологию ADO (мне подходит), но на шаге **Figure 7.3 Creating a new MySQL connection** у меня нет в списке MySql Database, а при попытке использования `connectionStrings`, заданной мною в `web.config` следующим образом:

  ```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=localhost; 
    user id=root; password=some-password; database=booksdb" 
    providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  ```

  мне все равно не удалось установить соединение с mysql с помощью ADO, хотя я 
  добавил Entity Framework, MySql.Data.dll и MySql.Data.Entity в решение. 
  Непонятные костыли.

Я думаю, тут есть такие люди, кто сталкивался с данной проблемой и, надеюсь, сможет мне помочь.

Благодарю!

Comment: а чем metanit не устраивает?

Comment: @codename0082016 не устраивает тем, что там подход CodeFirst, т.е. на основе моделей автоматически генерируется база данных, а мне нужно наоборот, чтобы из уже существующей бд генерировались модели (сущности) или хотя бы просто создавалось ручное подключение к mysql, после которого я бы смог получить данные из базы данных.

Comment: вот это не подойдет http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30415437/creating-an-ado-net-entity-data-model-with-mysql-database

вот тут про коннекторы к MySQL https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-visual-studio-install.html

Comment: @Eikhner попробую, отпишусь вам, когда закончу

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/articles/mvc/23.php 

там в обсуждении ниже есть что то про подключение и миграцию

Comment: @Eikhner прочитайте внимательно мой вопрос. В первом пункте я уже обсуждал эту статью.

Comment: вот ещё немного , мож поможет  https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/8867/

Comment: вот тут подробно у человека описано подключение к имеющеися базе 

http://dwcryan.com/blog/configure-mysql-with-adonet-in-vs-2013/

Comment: @Eikhner благодарю! статья из англоязычного stackoverflow помогла мне.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перелопатив большое количество статей, я нашел решение. Спасибо пользователю [Eikhner](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/237127/eikhner) за присланную [статью](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30415437/creating-an-ado-net-entity-data-model-with-mysql-database).

Оказывается, что помимо установленных пакетов MySQL.Data, MySQL.Data.Entity и ПО MySQL Net Connector необходимо было предварительно поставить ПО MySQL for Visual Studio. После чего ADO.NET EDM после некоторых манипуляций с настройками MySQL сгенерировал модели.

Comment: Andrei Khotko, а Вы бы не могли более подробно описать некоторые манипуляции с настройками MySQL, потому как у меня не создается модель данных. К базе через Server Explorer все подключается нормально, а вот до этапа добавления таблиц в модель не доходит, окно мастера просто вылетает и все...